# I Have MySQL Query I Would Like To Make Faster

Tags: php, mysql

```
$result1 = mysql_query("SELECT distinct city FROM postcodedb WHERE web='ALR' ORDER BY city") or die(mysql_error());
while($row1=mysql_fetch_array($result1)) {
    $city = $row1['city'];
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM postcodedb WHERE area='$city' AND city='$city' LIMIT 1") or die(mysql_error());
    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        $city = $row['city'];
    }
}
```

So in database records look like this:

```
---------------------
id  city     area
---------------------
1   Bromley  Bromley <- I need this record

2   Bromley  other1

3   Bromley  other2

4   Ilford   Ilford <- and then this one

5   Ilford   other1
---------------------
```

and there is more cities and areas assigned to these cities.

So, what I’m trying to get is a listing of ***distinct* cities**, but important is for me is that i get row ID where both `city` and `area` are the same??

This query works as I want it to work but is a bit slow, and I believe there is a better way to achieve the same result?

I hope I explained myself clearly.

Thank you very much in advance!

Nita

Comment: are "city" and "web" indexed?

Comment: Indexing and caching are about the only things you can do

Comment: how do i cache these values ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the city and area are the same, then that should be a condition in the query:

```
SELECT distinct city
FROM postcodedb
WHERE web = 'ALR' and city = area
ORDER BY city;
```

Ideally, there would be no duplicates, so you can eliminate the `distinct`:

```
SELECT city
FROM postcodedb
WHERE web = 'ALR' and city = area
ORDER BY city;
```

And for this query you would want an index on `postcodedb(web, city, area)` for optimal performance.

Comment: For performance, you would have one query instead of two !?!?

Answer (score 0):

```
    $result1 = mysql_query("SELECT distinct city FROM postcodedb WHERE web = 'ALR' and city = area ORDER BY city") or die(mysql_error()); 
while($row1=mysql_fetch_array($result1)) {
$city = $row1['city'];
}
```

1  query instead of 2. Visible increase on performance. Works so much faster.

Thank you Guys.